# jquery code not working for all selection options

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery code does not alert for all options I have in select element, instead jquery only alerts for 1 of the Select option. Please see the below code

I did spent hours to get this fix by checking solution online, but no success

```
    <div>
      <h4>Company name</h4>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option></option>
        <option>Updated</option>
        <option>Validated</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>Owner name</h4>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option></option>
        <option>Updated</option>
        <option>Validated</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>Address </h4>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option></option>
        <option>Updated</option>
        <option>Validated</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>Vertical</h4>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option></option>
        <option>Updated</option>
        <option>Validated</option>
      </select>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group" style="margin:100px;">
      <label for="comment" style="float:left;">Comment:</label> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="get_comment_button" role="button" style="float:left;">Get Comment</button>
      <textarea class="comment-box" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
 </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#get_comment_button").on('click',function(){

        var optionText = $("#sel1 option:selected").text();
        if (optionText == "updated") {
          $("#comment").html("Team Updated on ");
        }else {
          $("#comment").html("Team Validated on ");
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used same `id` in all `<select>`. Id should be unique. So, you can add same `class` in all `<select>` tags.

**Here is the Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sel1").on('change',function(){
var optionText = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
        alert("Selected Option Text: "+optionText);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<h4>Company name</h4>
 <select id="sel1" class="sel1">
  <option></option>
  <option>Updated</option>
  <option>Validated</option>
</select> 
</div>
<div>
<h4>Owner name</h4>
 <select id="sel1" class="sel1">
  <option></option>
  <option>Updated</option>
  <option>Validated</option>
</select> 
</div>
<div>
<h4>Address </h4>
 <select id="sel1" class="sel1">
  <option></option>
  <option>Updated</option>
  <option>Validated</option>
</select> 
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Vertical</h4>
 <select id="sel1" class="sel1">
  <option></option>
  <option>Updated</option>
  <option>Validated</option>
</select> 
</div>

<div class="form-group" style="margin:100px;">
 <label for="comment" style="float:left;">Comment:</label> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="get_comment_button" role="button" style="float:left;">Get Comment</button>
<textarea class="comment-box" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ID` attribute is unique per document and your code does not work in an intended way because you are repeating the same `ID`. Either use unique IDs or attach an event to the `<select>`

Also as a side note, it would also be a good practice to use `console.log()` for debugging instead of `alert()`

```js
var company_name = $('#company_name');
var owner_name = $('#owner_name');
var address = $('#address');
var vertical = $('#vertical');


$("#get_comment_button").on('click', function() {

  if (company_name.val() == "Updated" ||
    owner_name.val() == "Updated" ||
    address.val() == "Updated" ||
    vertical.val() == "Updated") {
    $("#comment").html("Team Updated on ");
  } else {
    $("#comment").html("Team Validated on ");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <h4>Company name</h4>
  <select id="company_name">
    <option></option>
    <option>Updated</option>
    <option>Validated</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Owner name</h4>
  <select id="owner_name">
    <option></option>
    <option>Updated</option>
    <option>Validated</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Address </h4>
  <select id="address">
    <option></option>
    <option>Updated</option>
    <option>Validated</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Vertical</h4>
  <select id="vertical">
    <option></option>
    <option>Updated</option>
    <option>Validated</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" style="margin:100px;">
  <label for="comment" style="float:left;">Comment:</label> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="get_comment_button" role="button" style="float:left;">Get Comment</button>
  <textarea class="comment-box" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I am looking to achieve on click function : $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#get_comment_button").on('click',function(){
        
        var optionText = $("#sel1 option:selected").text();
        if (optionText == "updated") {
          $("#comment").html("Team Updated on ");
        }else {
          $("#comment").html("Team Validated on ");
        }
    });
});

Comment: mate, you need to update the question with this. its not clear where the button and the comment div is

Comment: @Riyaz you need to update your POST, not my answer mate. I have rejected your edit of the answer

Comment: Sorry about that, just updated code, Thank you for helping

Comment: so on button click, which select box are you checking? as i said, the ID needs to be unique, so is your intention to check all the select boxes?

Comment: Yes, my intention is to select all select box, so I can select few as update and few as validate. If 1 option is update and reset all validate, comment should read as Team updated, and if 0 update and all validate comment should read as Team Validates. Thank you again

Comment: Woow, thanks that works, I see what logic you use in here. Also, how can I make todays date appear post comment ends?

Comment: Fixed the date issue , here is the code I added :var output = (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + '-' +
    (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
    d.getFullYear(); $("#comment").html("Support Team Validated on "+output);

Comment: okay, i think if you have figured it out, you dont need to add here.

Comment: please feel free to accept the answer if the posted issue is resolved